# dotnetopenauth - popup window does not close after authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dotnetopenauth

I'm using dotnetopenauth to as my open id lib. in all browsers the popup being close after authentication except for IE. I'm doing the authentication as follows:

Using window.open I opens the Authenticate action and after successfully authenticate return the following view:

```
    if (window.opener.isUserLoggedOn()) {
        window.opener.OnUserLogonFinished();
        window.close();
    }
    else {
        window.close();
    }
```

In all browsers the opener is accessible except for IE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the standard pop-up windows hosted and controlled by DotNetOpenAuth or have you spun your own?

One issue I ran into is that if your IE popup window changes zones (Internet to Intranet or Trusted) during redirect that it permanently breaks the relationship between the child and parent window.  But fortunately that usually isn't an issue once you go to production since your site will be in the Internet zone for your users as will most of the users' Providers.

Comment: I tried go production and it solved the problem so I'm guessing you are right. thanks!

Comment: I think we might be encountering this right now...will need to wait until we get to production to be sure.  (It would be swell if the javascript with the error had a comment about this possibility; I luckily googled and got this page.)